# PyQt5: Does QtableView have a "changedselection" SIGNAL?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a clicked signal but I would like to use a "changed selection" signal, I didn't find in the documentation.

```
self.ui.tableView.clicked.connect(self.func_test)
```

to use something like: (if that exists)

```
self.ui.tableView.changedselection.connect(self.func_test)
```

From the documentation, Qtableview has no signals, herits from QAbstractItemView which has these ONLY signals?!

Signals:

```
def activated (index)
def clicked (index)
def doubleClicked (index)
def entered (index)
def iconSizeChanged (size)
def pressed (index)
def viewportEntered ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Selection of a class that inherits from [`QAbstractItemView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html), like the [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), are handled by the [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) and it has the required [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal:

```py
# The model must be established before
# self.ui.tableView.setModel(your_model)
self.ui.tableView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.func_test)
```

**Note:** This method has to be placed after setting the model to the QTableView

Comment: Yea, I saw alsothat on some posts, but when I try, it doesnt work: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectionChanged'